# How to Type TAB in Notepad++ when 'Replace by Space' is Enabled?

Tags: notepad++, text-editors

With the 'Replace by Space' option enabled in Notepad++ (*`Preferences > Language > Replace by Space`*), is there is a key combination which inserts a tab character without it being replaced by spaces?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>009</kbd>, with the `009` being typed on the numeric keypad. That'll send a <kbd>Tab</kbd> character, and in my testing, Notepad++ won't intercept and replace it, even with the `Replace by space` setting enabled.

(You can probably get away with just `09`, but I was taught long ago that <kbd>Alt</kbd> sequences should always be at least three characters.)

Comment: Can't believe I didn't think of that! I'll probably program that as a macro with a keyboard shortcut of Ctrl+TAB or similar. Many thanks!